# Access choice labels directly from Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse - Unable to implement sample code

Tags: dataverse, azure-synapse-link

I am trying to work 'Choices', formerly known as OptionSets in Azure Dataverse.

I am trying to implement the sample code from the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-choice-labels

The code is as follows:

```
SELECT LocalizedLabel as statecode 
FROM databasename.dbo.account_partitioned 
LEFT JOIN databasename.dbo.OptionsetMetadata 
ON (databasename.dbo.OptionsetMetadata.Option = databasename.dbo.account_partitioned.statecode AND databasename.dbo.OptionsetMetadata.OptionSetName = statecode)
```

After executing the code, I get the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Option'.
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the error?

I also just the same code, with the square brackets, as follows:

```
SELECT [LocalizedLabel] as [statecode] 
FROM [databasename].[dbo].[account_partitioned] 
LEFT JOIN [databasename].[dbo].[OptionsetMetadata] 
ON ([databasename].[dbo].[OptionsetMetadata].[Option] = [databasename].[dbo].[account_partitioned].[statecode] AND [databasename].[dbo].[OptionsetMetadata].[OptionSetName] = statecode)
```

But I got the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ']'.
```